# Python, finding item in a list with variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am not a programmer, so this might be very basic.
I am trying to find the index of a variable inside a list with the contents of a variable

```
name = "Carl"
num = 10
more = "stuff"

my_list = [name, num, more]

target = "num"
targetVal = "25"

print(my_list)
print(my_list.index(target))
```

I get

```
['Carl', 10, 'stuff']
ValueError: 'num' is not in list
```

Indexing  `num` as variable works, but  `"num"` will not work.

So I can't find a way of changing the num ="10" inside my list to "25". This way of a list would be perfect for what I am trying to hack together, but I can't figure out how to do it.

**EDIT:**

Using dictionarys instead of lists seams to be better

```
my_dict = {"name": "Carl", "num": "10", "more": "stuff"}
target = "num"
targetVal = "25"

print(my_dict)
print(my_dict[target])

my_dict[target] = targetVal

print(my_dict[target])
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'Carl', 'num': '10', 'more': 'stuff'}
10
25
```

Comment: It would be better to just store `name`, `num` and `more` in a dictionary. Then it's just `your_dict[target] = targetVal`. Trying to use bare variables here is going to make it messier than it needs to be.

Comment: @Carcigenicate answer is working. dict seem to be made for that. Thanks you and the other answers very much!

Comment: generally speaking, be careful to distinguish between the name of a variable and a string containing that name.  there is often no overlap/relationship whatsoever between the 2 and for people very new to programming it makes sense that the string `"num"` and the variable `num` are somehow related and *the computer ought to know that*.  Python actually does support this type of discovery, through dictionaries (as in your example), namespaces, locals(), globals() and other advanced mechanisms, but at a beginner level assume that, no, the computer will not necessarily know that.

Answer (score 2):

Your values in a list (`my_list`) are string so string should be in single or double quotes like this:

```
name = "Carl"
num = 10
more = "stuff"

my_list = ["name", "num", "more"]

target = "num"
targetVal = "25"

print(my_list)
print(my_list.index(target))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = ['Carl', 10, 'stuff']
num = 10
index = my_list.index(num)
my_list[index] = 15
print(my_list) #['Carl', 15, 'stuff']
```